# AWS SAM Event bridge not triggering lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-event-bridge

I have created a lambda function in my sam template and have added a Eventbridge rule linked to  s3 bucket  trigger the lambda whenever a file arrives inside the bucket. However, when i add a new file in the s3 bucket  the lambda function does nottriggered.

below is code for lambda function

```
  TimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: cc-dummy-eventbridge-lambda
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      CodeUri: ./TimeZone
      Role: !FindInMap
        - StagesMap
        - Ref: Environments
        - RoleEnv
      Events: 
        GetEvent:
          Type: EventBridgeRule
          Properties:
            Pattern:
              source:
                - "aws.s3"
              detail:
                eventName:
                  - "PutObject"
                  - "PutObjectAcl"
                  - "CopyObject"
                requestParameters:
                  bucketName:
                    - !FindInMap [StagesMap, !Ref Environments, SOURCEBUCKET]
```

My eventbridge rule pattern that has been created:

```
Event pattern:
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "dummy-dev"
      ]
    },
    "eventName": [
      "Object Created"
    ]
  }
}
```

What am i missing in code that will enable the eventbridge trigger to work ?

Comment: What makes you think there are EventBridge events for incoming s3 objects?

Comment: *"What am i missing in code that will enable the s3 trigger to work ?"* - you did miss to actually create a trigger, that is an S3 feature and you simply do not use it at all.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the eventbridge trigger has been linked to an s3 bucket which is connected to the lambda function. when a new file arrives in the s3 bucket, it should trigger the eventbridge rule which will result in lambda function being triggered

Comment: That misses both points of my comments: 1. EventBridge does generally not receive events from S3 data api calls. 2. there is something that is explicitly called "s3 trigger" and you should use that mechanism instead. There are no "eventbridge triggers", there are rules, patterns, targets, schedules, ... but no triggers.

Comment: i have managed to fix the issue by changing the code a bit around which i have added below. maybe my question was not clear

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the eventbridge issue by changing the ***detail-type***  and changing the ***bucketname***.  i have added the code below that has fixed the issue that i was having

```
 GetEvent:
          Type: EventBridgeRule
          Properties:
            EventBusName: default
            Pattern:
              source:
                - "aws.s3"
              detail-type:
                - Object Created 
              detail:
                bucket:
                  name:
                    - !FindInMap [StagesMap, !Ref Environments,SOURCEBUCKET]
```